# String with spaces into table php

Tags: php, string

I have a pretty basic question. I have an output from a string operation and it looks like this

```
echo $var4;
// output T1 T2 a b a1 b1 a2 b2 a3 b3
```

I want to convert them in HTML table (T1 & T2 are table headers)

```
 T1 | T2
 a  | b
 a1 | b1
 a2 | b2
 a3 | b3
```

Please let me know how to achieve this using PHP?

Comment: It'd be easier if you show your code.

Comment: What do you mean by "tabular format"? As values in an array or as output in some markup like html that renders as a table?

Comment: I have edited the question and made it more specific! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explode the string and then chunk the resulting array:

```
$str = 'T1 T2 a b a1 b1 a2 b2 a3 b3';
$items = explode(' ', $str);
$chunks = array_chunk($items, 2);
var_dump($chunks);
```

Exploding the string will give you this:

```
['T1', 'T2', 'a', 'b', 'a1', 'b1', 'a2', 'b2', 'a3', 'b3']
```

Chunking the array into pieces with 2 items gives you this:

```
[
    ['T1', 'T2'],
    ['a', 'b'],
    ['a1', 'b1'],
    ['a2', 'b2'],
    ['a3', 'b3'],
]
```

To put it into a table:

```
<?php
$str = 'T1 T2 a b a1 b1 a2 b2 a3 b3';
$items = explode(' ', $str);
$chunks = array_chunk($items, 2);
?>
<table>
    <?php foreach($chunks as $chunk): ?>
        <tr>
        <?php foreach ($chunk as $item): ?>
            <td><?php echo $item ?></td>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey, is there a way to convert them in HTML Table format?